# Changing badge value text and background color in MoreNavigationController TableView Row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've fully customized the MoreNavigationController but I cannot figure out the last bit... how do you change the badge text and background color for the tableview row?  See the image below...

[image: BadgeColor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... add to your tabBarController class:

```
UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

Then set:

```
moreNavigationController.delegate = self
```

Then add this:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if (self.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.title == "More"){
            let moreTableView = self.moreNavigationController.topViewController!.view as! UITableView

            for cell in moreTableView.visibleCells {

                for views in cell.subviews {

                   // print(views.description.contains("_UITableViewCellBadgeNeue"))

                    for items in views.subviews {
                        if (items is UILabel) {
                            let item = items as! UILabel
                            item.textColor = UIColor.white
                            item.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 27, green: 27, blue: 27, transparancy: 100)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```